# Removing query_string from URL after rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageId=9523&contentURL=10$
RewriteRule ^master_template\.aspx$ community/returned-volunteers/stay-involved [R=301,L]
```

This works (sort of)...

Instead of `www.example.com/master_template.aspx?PageId=9523&contentURL=10`

I end up with `www.example.com/community/returned-volunteers/stay-involved?PageId=9523&contentURL=10`

The URL I want is `www.example.com/community/returned-volunteers/stay-involved`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Remove the QUERY_STRING from the URL](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html#delete-query-string).

**Cleaning it up**

The solution to resolve this problem is incredibly easy, so much so, you need just one character. How is it done? Ironically, the question mark is the answer. You simply have to amend your original rule by adding a question mark after the substitution so / becomes /?

rewriterule ^oldpage.php$ /? [R=301,L]

This will now rewrite oldpage to the site root and clear up the query string so you have a nice, clean rewrite. The question is the answer!

Comment: Yep worked it out but didn't give it such a classy explanation! Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add a question mark to the end of the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^master_template\.aspx$ community/returned-volunteers/stay-involved? [R=301,L]
```